# Is it possible to run Dir.glob remotely with capistrano

Tags: capistrano, glob, rake-task

When running a capistrano rake task, `Dir.glob('paths/*/')` is executed locally.

Is there a way to list remote folders with `Dir.glob` in order to run a command on each of them ?

This script should download all folders matching the `glob`. For now it downloads all folders that are already present locally.

```
  desc 'Download generated folders'
  task :download_folders do
    folders = *Dir.glob('path/*/*')
    run_locally do
      module_templates.each do |p|
        begin
          puts p
          execute :mkdir, "-p #{p}"
          execute :scp, "-r user@example.com:#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current/#{p}/* #{p}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```